# IIs issue with javascript files has special character like "test~1.js"

Tags: c#, angular, iis

IIs issue with JavaScript files has special character like "test~1.js"
when i call it throw iis i get net::ERR_ABORTED 404 error

GET [https://client.dtcm.com/default~hotel-consumption-form-consumption-form-module~hotel-dashboard-dashboard-module~hotel-faq-fa~6dad6b16.js](https://client.dtcm.com/default%7Ehotel-consumption-form-consumption-form-module%7Ehotel-dashboard-dashboard-module%7Ehotel-faq-fa%7E6dad6b16.js) net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: I don’t think the problem is caused by the special character. If there is no special character, the js file will work normally? If you try to open "test~1.js" in your browser directly, does it load? Is that the right path relative to the root that's being served by your dev web server?

Comment: Once I removed ~ character it is working properly

Comment: I think there are something block url when it is contains '~1'

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following to your web.config file, If set the attribute allowDoubleEscaping to true, request filtering will allow URLs with doubly-escaped characters.

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```